# Which Ubuntu version

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, versions

I wonder which Ubuntu release version I should use.

My machine have to contain/run a hostapd wifi AP, an OpenVPN connexion, and LUKS encryption. That's all. I detail it if ever it can make sense in deciding which version I should install.

I need nothing exotic at all, to avoid configuration rarities or useless particularities.

My project runs well on Mint 17+ today. I'll need to remake it on Ubuntu, LUKS encrypted, disk. What version should I choose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing an LTS version is always the best bet, as they're developed and supported for 5 years, rather than the 9 months of non LTS releases.

The most current LTS version is 14.04, although 12.04 is still supported, the next one won't be released until April 2016.

I favor Ubuntu server editions, as I like to do everything on the command-line and it's less resource heavy, as it doesn't need to run all that graphical stuff!

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, installing Ubuntu is no different than installing Linux Mint. Linux Mint is basically Ubuntu with a different desktop environment. 

As fart as Ubuntu versions go, an LTS version will be the best. The latest one will be supported the longest. While its been a while since I used Ubuntu (I am currently using Linux Mint 17.2), I have had the most luck with Ubuntu 14.04. 

If you are running an older machine, you should use Lubuntu, Xubuntu, or Ubuntu server. I am using an old desktop machine, and Ubuntu is always having problems on it. The Unity desktop is very resource heavy.

So, I would probably recommend Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I had bet that if I leave Mint for Ubuntu, I get a better OS without Mint layer. But if it is only a matter of environment, I'll maybe keep going with Mint.